# How MarkLogic store table data and how can i query it . In what form data saved?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Can MarkLogic store table data if yes how can i query it and in what form data saved ?

I want to have data like we save in hive. So if I want to save same data in MarKLogic how it will looks like and how can i retrieve the data.

Comment: Will Schema database or collection can help on this ,, if yes how can i use it ?

Answer (score 3):

For what you want, you would convert your content into a a structured format (JSON, XML) and store that. Then you would be able to query it.

The rest of your question I disregarded as too vague (and too many questions in a single post). Find the links below as a starting point to help you understand the product:

Getting Started
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/getting-started/intro

Loading Content
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/intro

Free intro Course (all courses are free)
http://www.marklogic.com/training-courses/marklogic-fundamentals/

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes i guess can save each row of table in one xml and name or xml would be primary key , right. I want to know how can i differentiate those xmls so i can identify and query those xml separately. I found collection may help but it will be tough to add collection in each xml as table is having around 100 of rows.

Comment: @user7006501, your question seems to indicate no understanding of how to query in MarkLogic.  Please read through the training materials provided.

Comment: @user7006501 David, I might also include [MarkLogic Data Modeling Guidlines](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-modeling) as well.